How do I compute the ground state starting from a Nambu-like representation of the system?
I'm aware that the ground state
$$|{\Omega}>= \Pi_{|k|<k_f} c^\dagger_{k,\sigma} |{0}>$$
is a product up to the Fermi momentum of construction operators acting on the vacuum. In this case, in order to execute this product explicitly I can represent the construction operators as matrices of ones and zeroes.
However, when I'm in a Nambu-like basis representation
$$
H = \sum_k \Psi^\dagger h(k) \Psi,
$$
where
$$
\Psi^\dagger = [c_k, c_k^\dagger] 
$$
how do I compute the ground state explicitly? All I have is a Hamiltonian $$h(k),$$ it's eigenvalues and eigenstates, is there a general way to obtain
$$|{\Omega}>$$
from this information only?

Just to clarify: $\prod_{k<k_F;;s=\uparrow,\downarrow} c^{\dagger}_{k,s} |0\rangle$ is the ground state for a system of non interacting fermions. In general the ground state is different
